# Detect a specific file change in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

We have have certain files in our solutions and I would like to detect changes to those specific files.

If a change is found to a specific file I would like to receive an email.

Is this possible via teamcity or mercurial (our VCS)

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use TeamCity for this? It sounds like task for mercurial hooks http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Hook

Comment: @Eli: Did you find answer to this question? I am also in same situation like yours.

Comment: @Govs: In the end this was done using hooks from our VCS. We are using Kiln which supports triggers for check-ins. The trigger pushes the information to a windows service that sends off an email if certain rules have been identified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this with TeamCity, you can do this:

1. Setup a build configuration, attach your VCS to it.
2. Set your [checkout rules](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/VCS+Checkout+Rules) to match only files you are interested in.
3. Add a build step (maybe, do some tests?)
4. Add VCS trigger.
5. Subscribe to "build start" event of this build configuration in "My Settings & Tools"

Comment: What if you want to detect changes in certain files but all files are needed for a successful build?

Comment: @wes2020 you can filter files in VCS Trigger. Check the `advanced options`